# how to ignore dir-prop-base in .svn folder?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I've read several posts here about ignoring files in Mercurial but I'm stumped on this one.

I have a couple of .svn files in my repository (I'm using hg for local commits, then pushing to svn). The files are:

```
Apps\.svn\dir-prop-base 
Apps\.svn\entries
```

I've got several ignore entries in my `.hgignore` but none of them seem to be covering these two files.

```
syntax: glob
.svn/*
**/.svn/**.*
syntax: regexp
\.svn\\*
```

I'm trying a couple of things to see which sticks there. To me, it looks like those files should be ignored twice. The strange thing is that `Apps\.svn\all-wcprops` is being ignored. Clearly I'm missing something. I'm checking whether the files are ignored by opening a new status window using TortoiseHg. I can't detect any difference between that and `hg status`.

Comment: Could it be that they are already tracked (by accident)? In that case the ignore file wouldn't apply to them until they are untracked. `hg status -A Apps\.svn\dir-prop-base` should tell you, see `hg help status` for other useful options.

Comment: You might be right. The status is showing as "A". Does that mean it's already under tracking? This is a brand new repo that I'm adding the files to for the first time.

Comment: Yeah, A means it's already added and adding overrides ignore.  Do a `hg forget` on them and you'll see they'll be ignored.

Comment: @Oben: I think you were right. I hadn't made my first commit to the repo but Apps\.svn\dir-prop-base was showing as an add. Still, that doesn't seem like the right answer (deleting the repo and running hg init after making .hgignore). Seems like I should be able to force hg to check the ignore status on files again if they haven't been added yet.

Comment: @Oben: I think you pointed me in the right direction. Make an answer about undoing the Add etc. and I'll edit it to be the right answer so you get the credit.

Comment: @jcollum: Thanks for the credit offer, but feel free to write the answer yourself, once the issue is clarified. By the way, why don't you use [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home) for your HG-SVN use case?

Comment: @Oben: I'm not familiar with that. I'm making a hg repo that I can use to store my local changes because the svn repo is locked out right now -- I need to be able to put my changes somewhere else in the meantime. I don't want to interact with svn at all right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oben pointed me in the right direction. He declined making an answer, so here it is:

The files that you want to ignore **can't be in an Add state when you are editing the ignore file** (since Add takes precedence over Ignore apparently). So my solution was to do `hg revert`, edit the ignore file, then use `hg status [directory] -i` to see which files in the target directory would be ignored. Repeat until all the correct files are ignored, then use `hg add`.

Answer (score 0):

```
syntax: regexp
^.*\.svn/dir-prop-base$
```

works for me.

Comment: Right, I mean I can add entries for every file that I want to ignore. But why would the ignores that I have not catch these two files?

Comment: Actually this isn't working for me. 'Apps\.svn\dir-prop-base' is still showing up as an Add.

Comment: Clarification: above works in Linux, but I do believe '/' should work as a directory separator in windows too. Can you post your hgignore file?

Comment: It's posted above. There's an extra entry for bin/** in glob, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The following simple `.hgignore` works fine for me to ignore all .svn folders (on Windows, hg 1.7):

```
syntax: glob
.svn
```